# How would I switch screens from a .py file while the screens are managed in a main .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I have three codes,  I am confused with how I would navigate to the next screen in my Organize.kv from my login.py, I have the main kv file that has all the screens saved and the login python and kv file that manages the login screen, the login kv file balances two different tabs, so far I have the create tab that sends you to the create class of the login python file which is connected to mysql, how would I switch screens to the Main Menu which is in the main Organize.kv file from the login python file? Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm super warn out from trying to figure this out.

Anything helps, thank you

The main Organize.kv that has all the screens

```
#:import organize organize
#:import navigation_screen_manager navigation_screen_manager
#:import anchorlayout_with_action_bar anchorlayout_with_action_bar
#:import sharpen_skills sharpen_skills
#:import login login
<MainMenu@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "40dp"
    spacing: "20dp"
    size_hint: .7, .9
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
    Button:
        text: "Organize"
        on_press: app.manager.push("screen2")
    Button:
        text: "Journal"
        on_press: app.manager.push("screen3")
    Button:
        text: "Sharpen Skills"
        on_press: app.manager.push("SkillsExamplesTabs")
    Button:
        text: "Exit"
        on_press: app.stop()

<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen:
        name: "Login"
        title: "login"
        LoginTabs:
    Screen:
        name: "MainMenu"
        MainMenu:
    Screen:
        name: "screen2"
        AnchorLayoutWithActionBar:
            title: "Organize"


    Screen:
        name: "screen3"
        AnchorLayoutWithActionBar:
            title: "Journal"

    Screen:
        name: "SkillsExamplesTabs"
        AnchorLayoutWithActionBar:
            title: "Sharpen Skills"
            SkillsExamplesTabs:
```

My login.kv file

```
<LoginTabs@TabbedPanel>:
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Create Account"
        Create:
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Login"
        Login:
```

and finally my login.py file

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
import mysql.connector
import navigation_screen_manager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from navigation_screen_manager import NavigationScreenManager

Builder.load_file("login.kv")
Builder.load_file("Organize.kv")

sm = ScreenManager()

class MyScreenManager(NavigationScreenManager):
    pass

class Create(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.warning = Label(text="", pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        user_label = Label(text="Username", size_hint=(.5, .5),
                           pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        self.user_textinput = TextInput(text='Enter Username')
        pas_label = Label(text="Password", size_hint=(.5, .5),
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        self.pas_textinput = TextInput(text="enter Password")
        enter_button = Button(text="Create")
        with user_label.canvas:
            Color(0, .25, 1, .25)
        enter_button.bind(on_press=self.Add)
        self.add_widget(self.warning)
        self.add_widget(user_label)
        self.add_widget(self.user_textinput)
        self.add_widget(pas_label)
        self.add_widget(self.pas_textinput)
        self.add_widget(enter_button)

    def Add(self, btn):
        print("Working")
        t1 = self.user_textinput.text
        t2 = self.pas_textinput.text
        print(f"T1 = {t1} and {t2}")
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            user='root',
            password='*******',
            host='127.0.0.1',
            database='Usersdb')
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
            sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (user_name, user_pass) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            val = (t1,t2)
            mycursor.execute(sql,val)
            conn.commit()
        except:
            self.warning = "Username Already Taken"

class Login(StackLayout):
    pass
```

And finally my App class

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from navigation_screen_manager import NavigationScreenManager

class MyScreenManager(NavigationScreenManager):
    pass

class Organizer(App):

    manager = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        self.manager = MyScreenManager()
        return self.manager

Organizer().run()
```

And my Navigation Screen Manager

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


class NavigationScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    screen_stack = []

    def push(self, screen_name):
        self.screen_stack.append(self.current)
        self.transition.direction = "left"
        self.current = screen_name

    def pop(self):
        if len(self.screen_stack) > 0:
            screen_name = self.screen_stack[-1]
            del self.screen_stack[-1]
            self.transition.direction = "right"
            self.current = screen_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not include your `App` class, so a specific answer is impossible. The fact that you have multiple `kv` files is irrelevant once those `kv` files are loaded. In general, you just set the `current` property of the `ScreenManager` to the `name` of the `Screen` that you want displayed.

Again, the fact that you have multiple `kv` files is irrelevant once those `kv` files are loaded. So in any of the `kv` files, I believe that you should be able to use:

```
app.manager.push("MainMenu")
```

or:

```
app.manager.current = "MainMenu"
```

to get to the `MainMenu` `Screen`.

Comment: I posted my App class, I should have known to post that before, I apologize

Comment: What is `NavigationScreenManager`? I cannot find any such class.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. You must access your screen manager in order to set the current screen which is your active screen. In your `App` class, I recommend saving  your screen manager as an attribute via the `on_start` function.

```
class MyApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        screen_manager = self.root
```

From there, you could set your current screen using callback methods in kivy or python.

```
#in kv
on_release: setattr(app.screen_manager, 'current', 'the next screen name')

#in python
def set_screen_callback(self, instance *args):
    app.screen_manager.current = "the next screen name"
```

Comment: I implemented the python callback method, no error was thrown, the method was called, but the screen stayed on the Login

Comment: Check the instance of 'root'. ```print(app.root)```. Ensure that is a screen manager.